# How to change dataframe values when you need select different columns for every row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in the following form:

`W1 W2 W3 W4 W5 W6 W7 W8
 0  0  1  0  1  1  1  1
 0  0  1  0  0  1  1  1
 0  1  0  0  1  1  0  0
 1  0  0  0  1  1  0  1`

There is a parameter DIFF = **3**. 
I'm looking at every row for columns from W1 to **W4** and search for last **1**. It will be in columns W3, W3, W2, W1. Subsequently I change to 0 next 3 (DIFF) elements on the right side of this 1 in the whole row. 
See example, I marked those elements by x :

`W1 W2 W3 W4 W5 W6 W7 W8
 0  0  1  x  x  x  1  1
 0  0  1  x  x  x  1  1
 0  1  x  x  x  1  0  0
 1  x  x  x  1  1  0  1`

And final result:

`W1 W2 W3 W4 W5 W6 W7 W8
 0  0  1  0  0  0  1  1
 0  0  1  0  0  0  1  1
 0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0
 1  0  0  0  1  1  0  1`

Now, I have very convoluted solution that uses `iterrows()`, but I'm looking for a pandastic one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df = df.mask(df.cumsum(axis=1).ge(1).cumsum(axis=1).isin([2,3,4]), 0)
print (df)
   W1  W2  W3  W4  W5  W6  W7  W8
0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1
1   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1
2   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0
3   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   1
```

**Explanation**:

Use [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) per rows:

```
print (df.cumsum(axis=1))
   W1  W2  W3  W4  W5  W6  W7  W8
0   0   0   1   1   2   3   4   5
1   0   0   1   1   1   2   3   4
2   0   1   1   1   2   3   3   3
3   1   1   1   1   2   3   3   4
```

Comapre by `>=1` with [`ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ge.html):

```
print (df.cumsum(axis=1).ge(1))
      W1     W2    W3    W4    W5    W6    W7    W8
0  False  False  True  True  True  True  True  True
1  False  False  True  True  True  True  True  True
2  False   True  True  True  True  True  True  True
3   True   True  True  True  True  True  True  True
```

Again `cumsum` by boolen mask:

```
print (df.cumsum(axis=1).ge(1).cumsum(axis=1))
   W1  W2  W3  W4  W5  W6  W7  W8
0   0   0   1   2   3   4   5   6
1   0   0   1   2   3   4   5   6
2   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
3   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
```

Compare by `2,3,4` for next 3 values with omit first:

```
print (df.cumsum(axis=1).ge(1).cumsum(axis=1).isin([2,3,4]))
      W1     W2     W3    W4     W5     W6     W7     W8
0  False  False  False  True   True   True  False  False
1  False  False  False  True   True   True  False  False
2  False  False   True  True   True  False  False  False
3  False   True   True  True  False  False  False  False
```

More dynamic solution if want define `n` and `DIFF` values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'W1': [0, 0, 0, 0], 'W2': [0, 0, 1, 0], 
                   'W3': [1, 1, 0, 0], 'W4': [0, 0, 0, 0], 
                   'W5': [1, 0, 1, 0], 'W6': [1, 1, 1, 0], 
                   'W7': [1, 1, 0, 0], 'W8': [1, 1, 0, 1]})

print (df)
   W1  W2  W3  W4  W5  W6  W7  W8
0   0   0   1   0   1   1   1   1
1   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   1
2   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   0
3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
```

---

```
DIFF = 4
n = 3

#select columns for check by positions
subset = df.iloc[:, :n]
#replace 0 to NaNs replace back filling, change order of columns with cumsum
last_1 = subset.mask(subset == 0).bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, ::-1].cumsum(axis=1)
print (last_1)
    W3   W2   W1
0  1.0  2.0  3.0
1  1.0  2.0  3.0
2  NaN  1.0  2.0
3  NaN  NaN  NaN

#add missing columns and create ones rows by forward filling
df1 = last_1.reindex(index=df.index, columns=df.columns).ffill(axis=1)
print (df1)
    W1   W2   W3   W4   W5   W6   W7   W8
0  3.0  2.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
1  3.0  2.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
2  2.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN

#compare by 1 and get cumsum 
print (df1.eq(1).cumsum(axis=1))
   W1  W2  W3  W4  W5  W6  W7  W8
0   0   0   1   2   3   4   5   6
1   0   0   1   2   3   4   5   6
2   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

---

```
#last check range of values
df = df.mask(df1.eq(1).cumsum(axis=1).isin(range(2, DIFF + 2)), 0)
print (df)
   W1  W2  W3  W4  W5  W6  W7  W8
0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1
1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1
2   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
```

Comment: Really nice solution and explanation. Thank you!

Comment: @QuantChristo - I later realised first solution is not general, if change n or `DIFF` values, so added new one.

Answer (score 2):

Here is mixture of functional and pandastic approach:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'w1': [0, 1, 1, 0],
                   'w2': [1, 1, 0, 1],
                   'w3': [1, 0, 0, 0],
                   'w4': [0, 1, 1, 0],
                   'w5': [1, 1, 0, 1],
                   'w6': [0, 0, 1, 1],
                   'w7': [0, 1, 1, 0],
                   'w8': [1, 1, 1, 1]})



def errase_diff(row, n = 4, Diff = 3):
    """
    returns array with erassed diff values after last positive value
    in first n column
    """
    row_length = len(row)
    last_positive_id = [i for i, v in enumerate(row[:4]) if v == 1][-1]
    row[last_positive_id + 1: last_positive_id + 1 + Diff] = [0 for _ in range(Diff)]
    return row[:row_length]


df.apply(lambda x: errase_diff(x), 1)

   w1  w2  w3  w4  w5  w6  w7  w8
0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1
1   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   1
2   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   1
3   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   1
```

be aware that this solution erase data in your original df